# How to restore a partitioned PostgreSQL database without partitions?

Tags: postgresql

I have a partitioned Postgres database like:

- **items** - partitioned table
- **items_2022** - partition for 2022 data
- **items_2021** - partition for 2021 data

I would like to dump this database and then restore it on a new server *without* partitions, meaning I would like all data to simply be an items table that is not partitioned. Is there a way to do this using ***pg_dump*** and restore?